# How to remove admin bar logo in WordPress using plugin

Tags: admin-bar, logo

I'm following the instructions from [this page to remove the adminbar wordpress logo](http://codex.wordpress.org/remove_node#Remove_the_WordPress_Logo_from_the_Toolbar) and cannot quite understand why this is not working in a plugin I have created.

```
// Hide top left WordPress logo

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_logo', 999 );

function remove_wp_logo( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'wp-logo' );
}
```

Everything else in my plugin is working except this. Only difference I see in that example is that it is referring to the functions.php file?

Any thoughts would be appreciated?

Comment: Where in the plugin file are you using this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one does the job for us, we use WP3.7.1.

```
function no_wp_logo_admin_bar_remove() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'no_wp_logo_admin_bar_remove', 0);
```

Comment: Many thanks Charles that did the trick. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the below link:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer [see (help > deleted answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: Thanks Manish, I had a read through it and understand it a little better now.